# types for a function that can change the values of a nested Record

Tags: typescript, generics, types, arguments, wrapper

How to **derive return types from generic function arguments?**

With the following solution, P will be of type number ( because of the first argument ), and because of this, {value: 'myString'} will be marked as a wrong type.

```js
type MyGenericWrapper<T> = {value: T;}

// get all values out of the generic object wrappers
function allValues<P>(...args: MyGenericWrapper<P>[]) : P[] {
  return args.map(arg => arg.value);
}

const [a, b] = allValues({value: 1}, {value: 'myString'});
```

How can i tell the compiler that **P should be derived for every function argument?**

So that **a** will be of type number and **b** of type string

Comment: Using a mapped type in the return type: https://tsplay.dev/mqelZm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the generic parameter store the type of the entire array, and then use a mapped type in the return type:

```
function allValues<P extends MyGenericWrapper<any>[]>(...args: P): { [K in keyof P]: P[K]["value"] };
function allValues(...args: MyGenericWrapper<any>[]) {
  return args.map(arg => arg.value);
}
```

I'm using an overload here to keep the desired signature separate of the implementation (otherwise, you get annoying errors that require annoying fixes).

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqelZm)

Comment: Thank you very much. What about a scenario where i can not derive the type from the value property?
Like: {value: T | undefined, oldValue: T | 'not set' } ?

Comment: @ThomasDeutsch That would be a different question. Edit the question to include your real example, or ask another question.